# How to get query param from request in API Route handler?

Tags: rest, next.js

I'd like get query params from request in API call. How can I retreive it in server side?

```
import prisma from "@/app/lib/prisma";

import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import { Context } from "vm";

export async function getServerSideProps(ctx: Context) {
    const { igenykod } = ctx.params;
    return {
        props: {
            igenykod
        },
    };
};

export async function GET(
    req: NextApiRequest,
    res: NextApiResponse
) {
    const kod = req.query.igenykod as string
    const igenystatusz = await prisma.igenystatusz.findMany({
        where: {
            igenykod: "CK1"
        }
    });
    return new Response(JSON.stringify(igenystatusz));

}
```

In this code req.query is undefined. I readed about getServerSideProps but I dont want to make page for request. Can I make as simply as ExpressJS routing?

[image: My project structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [`app`](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure) directory (router), you can get query strings (aka the `?search=value`) in an [API route](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers) this way:

```typescript
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET(req: NextRequest) {
  const { searchParams } = new URL(req.url);
  console.log(searchParams.get("igenykod"));
  return new Response("...");
}
```

The API route handler only gets passed only the request, and its type is `NextRequest` not `NextApiRequest` which is for the [`pages`](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/project-structure) router (only where `getServerSideProps` works).

Answer (score 0):

Building on Youssouf response you can now access the search params directly in the `NextRequest`.

```js
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET(req: NextRequest) {
  const searchParams = req.nextUrl.searchParams;
  console.log(searchParams.get("igenykod"));
  return new Response("...");
}
```

You can read more about it [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/next-request).